# EF6 DbMigrations.Sql Method equivalent for Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Is there an EF Core equivalent way of using the SQL command to execute SQL statements? Eg. I want to 'seed' my db via a migration in core to insert some default values using in the UP method:

```
    public partial class PopulateGenresTable : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Jazz')");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found my own answer. In Core, I have to use the migrationBuilder method

```
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Name) VALUES ('Jazz')");
    }
```